# SQL Server: How can I select all result of table when condition is FALSE?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I got a trouble in stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
WHERE COUNT = CASE WHEN (@count = -1) THEN --SELECT ALL RESULT OF TESTTABLE--
ELSE @count END
```

When param @count is not equal -1, I want that query is the same with:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
```

I tried with

```
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
WHERE COUNT = CASE WHEN (@count <> -1) THEN @count END
```

But it's not true.

Comment: `WHERE @Count = -1 OR [Count] = @Count`, but it will probably give you somewhat bad performance. You should use dynamic SQL in this case

Comment: True, I'd use an object here.

Comment: Why not just split them with an IF statement?
`IF (@count = -1) BEGIN SELECT * FROM... END ELSE BEGIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE COUNT = @count`

Comment: Because I'm using many params in where clause, if I use IF statement for all condition, It's too complicated

Comment: @Lamak Ok, It's right. Thanks

Comment: This has the tell tale pattern of a catch all query. There are some serious performance considerations for this type of query. Check out this article on the topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a stored procedure, the best performance should come using 2 different queries:

```
if @count <> -1 
  SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
else
  SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE COUNT=@count
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a stored procedure you can use an if statement.  Something like:

```
IF @Count <> -1
BEGIN
   Select * From TestTable
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Select * From TestTable Where 1=0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE COUNT=@count OR @count = -1
```